# Setup Datapipeline Flow in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, debezium, data-lake, data-pipeline

Problem Statement: We have a Postgres RDS (Managed by AWS), and there is a requirement to set up a data lake (In S3) for all the data that are there in RDS. The data should be pushed to s3 on a near real-time basis, the solution should also take care of (Update, Insert, Delete Operations). There is a limitation that, we can't use the AWS Data Pipeline service because of its non-availability in the desired region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link is a great help, slight modifications here and there and it helped me setting up the pipeline.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/creating-a-source-to-lakehouse-data-replication-pipe-using-apache-hudi-aws-glue-aws-dms-and-amazon-redshift/

Answer (score 0):

There is AWS blog describing a solution which seem to meet your requirements or could be adjusted to it:

- [Stream changes from Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL using Amazon Kinesis Data Streams and AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/stream-changes-from-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-using-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-and-aws-lambda/)

Comment: Apache hudi and DMS along with Glue Custom connector was a great help